# search box of jQuery Datatable has search text above the search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable as follows:

```
var exTable1 = $("#exTable").DataTable({
    "language": {
        "search": "Filter",
        "searchPlaceholder": "search",
        "loadingRecords": "",
    },
    data: datasrc
    "dom": '<"top"lf>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
    "select": true,
    "processing": true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": 80,
    'columnDefs': [{
        'targets': 0,
        'orderable': false,
        'className': 'dt-body-center',
        'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<input type="checkbox">';
        }
    }],
});
```

This displays the search box as shown below:
[image: Search box]

How to get that Filter text beside the search box

Comment: there is no picture - and is css for sure, not js

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please ?

Comment: its a normal datatable..am wondering what causes that "Filter" text to go above the search box. If I manually edit the css using Inspect and set to "display: inline-block" it comes properly

Comment: please let me know how to set the css for the search box in the js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the css file did the trick:

```
.dataTables_filter input {
       display: inline-block !important;
}
```